# Maximum latitude map panning with leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new to leaflet and I want the restrict the panning of a world map horizontally and not vertically (longitude but not latitude) because this map will display pictures when I click on them and I cant see well the image when i restrict the panning horizontally AND vertically. The map by itself it not a picture, it's a real world map. But when I click on certain location, a small picture will appear on the map.

I try to play with maxBounds and setMaxbounds. The normal maxBounds (to view the world map) is :

```
maxBounds: [[-85, -180.0],[85, 180.0]],
```

When i try to put the latitude to

> [[-150, -180.0],[150, 180.0]]

, the vertical panning is still restricted. Can somebody help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds similar to a (quite obscure) issue in the Leaflet issue tracker a 
 while back: see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3081

However, that issue was dealing with infinite *horizontal* bounds, not vertical bounds *in a CRS that already has some preset limits*.

If you set the map's `maxBounds` to a value larger than 85 (the value for [`MAX_LATITUDE` of `L.Projection.Spherical`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/88dd22cfe89a209d19c061a813e99669844a921b/src/geo/projection/Projection.SphericalMercator.js#L17)) and run a debugger, the call stack goes through the map's `_panInsideMapBounds()`, then `panInsideBounds()`, then `_limitCenter()`, then `_getBoundsOffset`, then `project()`, then through the map CRS's `latLngToPoint`, then untimately `L.Projection.Spherical`'s `project()`. `L.Projection.Spherical.project()` projects the bounds' limits into pixel coordinates, **and** [clamps the projected point](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/88dd22cfe89a209d19c061a813e99669844a921b/src/geo/projection/Projection.SphericalMercator.js#L22) to be inside the projection's limits.

There are a lot of reasons behind this, one of them being to prevent users from putting markers outside the area covered with tiles:

[image: screenshot clamping markers]

(This is particularly important when a user confuses lat-lng with lng-lat and tries to use a value outside the [-90,90] range for latitude, and the projection code starts returning `Infinity` values everywhere)

How to get around this? Well, we can always specify the map's CRS, and we can create a CRS with a hacked projection which enforces a different limit. Please be aware that this changes how the `pixelOrigin` works internally (as explained in the [Leaflet tutorial about extending layers](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html)), so stuff (particularly plugins) might break.

So something like:

```
var hackedSphericalMercator = L.Util.extend(L.Projection.SphericalMercator, {
  MAX_LATITUDE: 89.999
});

var hackedEPSG3857 = L.Util.extend(L.CRS.EPSG3857, {
  projection: hackedSphericalMercator
});

var map = new L.Map('mapcontainer', {
    crs: hackedEPSG3857,
});
```

Of course, then you can set up your own `maxBounds`:

```
var map = new L.Map('mapcontainer', {
    crs: hackedEPSG3857,
    maxBounds: [[-Infinity, -10], [Infinity, 10]]
});
```

In this case, the bounds' limits would still be clamped to `hackedSphericalMercator.MAX_LATITUDE`, but you should have enough wiggle room for your application.

---

As a side note: A radically different approach to this problem would be to use a different map projection. We're used to a spherical cylindrical projection, but that's not the only way to flatten the earth.

In particular, a [Transverse Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection) (or pretty much any other transverse cylindrical projection, for that matter) works pretty much in the same way, but wraps vertically instead of horizontally, and it's the projected *longitudes*, not latitudes, the ones which approach infinity asymptotically when approaching the [-180, 180] range. Let me borrow an image from its wikipedia article:

[image: transverse spherical projection diagram]

This implies a different set of challenges (namely finding some raster tiles appropriate for your application, including which prime meridian to use, and making proj4leaflet play nice), but it's definitely doable.